# VLC forces all videos to be the same size - cannot resize them

Tags: video, vlc

All videos I try to play with vlc are fixed with the same size, I can't resize them forcing to zoom in or out to fit the window.

Tried to purge config folder, unistalling and reinstalling.
With other video players the videos are working perfectly as expected.

**vlc version** `2.2.1+git20160310+r58688+34+15~ubuntu15.10.1`

**kernel version** `4.2.0-34-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 10 22:13:01 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

output of `lshw -c video`:

```
*-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GF106M [GeForce GT 555M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d0000000-d1ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b3ffffff ioport:6000(size=128) memory:d2000000-d207ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:35 memory:d2400000-d27fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:7000(size=64)
```

output of `modinfo i915`:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-34-generic/updates/dkms/i915.ko
license:        GPL and additional rights
description:    Intel Graphics
author:         Intel Corporation
author:         Tungsten Graphics, Inc.
firmware:       i915/skl_dmc_ver1.bin
srcversion:     D8F27CD62AA99DAC898A0F1
alias:          pci:v00008086d00005A84sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001A84sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000A84sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000192Asv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000192Bsv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001926sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000191Dsv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000191Asv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000191Bsv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001912sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000191Esv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001921sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001916sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000190Asv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000190Bsv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001902sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000190Esv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001906sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000022B3sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000022B2sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000022B1sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000022B0sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000162Dsv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000162Asv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000162Esv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000162Bsv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001626sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001622sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000161Dsv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000161Asv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000160Dsv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000160Asv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000161Esv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000161Bsv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001616sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001612sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000160Esv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000160Bsv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001606sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001602sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000155sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000157sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000F33sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000F32sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000F31sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000F30sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000D26sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000D16sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000D06sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000A2Esv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000A1Esv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000A0Esv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000A26sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000A16sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000A06sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000C26sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000C16sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000C06sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000426sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000416sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000406sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000D2Esv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000D1Esv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000D0Esv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000D2Bsv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000D1Bsv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000D0Bsv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000D2Asv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000D1Asv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000D0Asv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000D22sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000D12sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000D02sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000A2Bsv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000A1Bsv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000A0Bsv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000A2Asv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000A1Asv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000A0Asv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000A22sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000A12sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000A02sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000C2Esv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000C1Esv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000C0Esv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000C2Bsv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000C1Bsv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000C0Bsv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000C2Asv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000C1Asv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000C0Asv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000C22sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000C12sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000C02sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000042Esv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000041Esv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000040Esv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000042Bsv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000041Bsv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000040Bsv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000042Asv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000041Asv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000040Asv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000422sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000412sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000402sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000016Asv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000015Asv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000162sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000152sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000166sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000156sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000016Asv0000152Dsd00008990bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000126sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000116sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000106sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000010Asv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000122sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000112sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000102sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000046sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000042sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000A011sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000A001sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002E92sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002E42sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002E32sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002E22sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002E12sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002E02sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002A42sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002A12sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002A02sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000029D2sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000029C2sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000029B2sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000029A2sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002992sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002982sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002972sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000027AEsv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000027A2sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002772sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002592sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000258Asv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002582sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002572sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000358Esv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00003582sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002562sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00003577sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
depends:        drm_kms_helper,drm,video,i2c-algo-bit
vermagic:       4.2.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           modeset:Use kernel modesetting [KMS] (0=disable, 1=on, -1=force vga console preference [default]) (int)
parm:           panel_ignore_lid:Override lid status (0=autodetect, 1=autodetect disabled [default], -1=force lid closed, -2=force lid open) (int)
parm:           semaphores:Use semaphores for inter-ring sync (default: -1 (use per-chip defaults)) (int)
parm:           enable_rc6:Enable power-saving render C-state 6. Different stages can be selected via bitmask values (0 = disable; 1 = enable rc6; 2 = enable deep rc6; 4 = enable deepest rc6). For example, 3 would enable rc6 and deep rc6, and 7 would enable everything. default: -1 (use per-chip default) (int)
parm:           enable_dc:Enable power-saving display C-states. (-1=auto [default]; 0=disable; 1=up to DC5; 2=up to DC6) (int)
parm:           enable_fbc:Enable frame buffer compression for power savings (default: -1 (use per-chip default)) (int)
parm:           lvds_channel_mode:Specify LVDS channel mode (0=probe BIOS [default], 1=single-channel, 2=dual-channel) (int)
parm:           lvds_use_ssc:Use Spread Spectrum Clock with panels [LVDS/eDP] (default: auto from VBT) (int)
parm:           vbt_sdvo_panel_type:Override/Ignore selection of SDVO panel mode in the VBT (-2=ignore, -1=auto [default], index in VBT BIOS table) (int)
parm:           reset:Attempt GPU resets (default: true) (bool)
parm:           enable_hangcheck:Periodically check GPU activity for detecting hangs. WARNING: Disabling this can cause system wide hangs. (default: true) (bool)
parm:           enable_ppgtt:Override PPGTT usage. (-1=auto [default], 0=disabled, 1=aliasing, 2=full) (int)
parm:           enable_execlists:Override execlists usage. (-1=auto [default], 0=disabled, 1=enabled) (int)
parm:           enable_psr:Enable PSR (default: false) (int)
parm:           preliminary_hw_support:Enable preliminary hardware support. (int)
parm:           disable_power_well:Disable the power well when possible (default: true) (int)
parm:           enable_ips:Enable IPS (default: true) (int)
parm:           fastboot:Try to skip unnecessary mode sets at boot time (default: false) (bool)
parm:           prefault_disable:Disable page prefaulting for pread/pwrite/reloc (default:false). For developers only. (bool)
parm:           load_detect_test:Force-enable the VGA load detect code for testing (default:false). For developers only. (bool)
parm:           invert_brightness:Invert backlight brightness (-1 force normal, 0 machine defaults, 1 force inversion), please report PCI device ID, subsystem vendor and subsystem device ID to dri-devel@lists.freedesktop.org, if your machine needs it. It will then be included in an upcoming module version. (int)
parm:           disable_display:Disable display (default: false) (bool)
parm:           disable_vtd_wa:Disable all VT-d workarounds (default: false) (bool)
parm:           enable_cmd_parser:Enable command parsing (1=enabled [default], 0=disabled) (int)
parm:           use_mmio_flip:use MMIO flips (-1=never, 0=driver discretion [default], 1=always) (int)
parm:           mmio_debug:Enable the MMIO debug code for the first N failures (default: off). This may negatively affect performance. (int)
parm:           verbose_state_checks:Enable verbose logs (ie. WARN_ON()) in case of unexpected hw state conditions. (bool)
parm:           edp_vswing:Ignore/Override vswing pre-emph table selection from VBT (0=use value from vbt [default], 1=low power swing(200mV),2=default swing(400mV)) (int)
parm:           enable_guc_submission:Enable GuC submission (default:false) (bool)
parm:           guc_log_level:GuC firmware logging level (-1:disabled (default), 0-3:enabled) (int)
```

output of `lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use'`:

```
Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Comment: Some simple things to try: 1) Right click on the video and select Video --> Always Fit Window 2) Try the keyboard shortcuts Alt+2 and Alt+3 3) Experiment with the Video Output : Tools --> Preferences --> (Show Settings: All) --> Video --> Output Modules --> Video Output Module

Comment: sorry, none of these work

Comment: Try these two things and give us a feedback: 1) Create another user, login with it and try vlc. 2) Boot a ubuntu (15.10 I guess?) live system from USB or DVD and try vlc.

Comment: 1) a new user has exactly the same problem
2) no time to boot 15.10 from USB/DVD now, let's investigate on this system before that option

Comment: Read the question. I'm already using the last version from that repository.

Comment: Try running sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/master-daily && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade. This will update VLC to the latest development version.

Comment: The command from the second commment is a bit different, it will update VLC to version 3.0.

Comment: you are right... anyway same issue with vlc 3.0.0~~git20160226+r63712+37~ubuntu15.10.1
And you should have supposed that, as I said it worked perfectly before!

Comment: I see you have tried some of the more recent vlc builds. Consider building your own and see if this resolves the issue. I run a guide here: http://www.andrews-corner.org/ubuntu/vlc.html which I have updated today. On a clean VM this resizes, zooms, runs full screen etc with no issues. Caveat: this is development version and cannot be relied on completely. However I would be willing to create a subsection to build the release version if you have some success with this page (preferrably on a clean VM).

Comment: You seem to have a dual-card graphics setup, does forcing one or the other in the BIOS make a difference?

Comment: Please try with the Live CD for us - we need to know if it is hardware or software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by uninstalling the `libvdpau-va-gl1` package.

Comment: OIC. Perhaps another solution would have been to disable Hardware Accelerated Decoding in the vlc preferences: Tools --> Preferences --> Inputs / Codecs --> Hardware Accelerated Decoding --> Disable.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by uninstalling the `libvdpau-va-gl1` package.  This package is supposed to provides hardware acceleration.  From the package description:

> This library proposes a generic VDPAU library. It uses OpenGL under the hood to accelerate drawing and scaling and VA-API (if available) to accelerate video decoding.

When testing the package for myself, I did not have the resize problem, but playback was choppy and my swap filled up until VLC crashed, so apparently it can cause various problems.  To uninstall it:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge libvdpau-va-gl1
```

Answer (score -1):

Open vlc > Tools > Preferences > check Simple settings (at bottom left corner) > check Resize interface to video size > check all settings (at bottom left corner) > select Interface (at left pane) > Main interfaces > Qt > check Resize interface to the native video size > Save > Close > Restart vlc